# maps.google Geocoding Jquery calls with country codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Im trying to get a simple geo-location type address lookup thing going using the google maps geocode API using jQuery $.getJSON method.

US & UK postal/zip codes are working fine but i've come across random countries where I'm guessing zip address are the same as other countries and i need to be able to return the correct address.

Im using a select option for someone to pick their country which contains its code e.g. Afghanistan has AF tied to it however when i try pass in the country code I'm still getting the wrong results.

Is there a proper way to call the API or are the results just hit and miss.

Sample below :

Zip for Kabul,Chahar Asyab is 1051

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1051&sensor=false
```

Will return addresses for Sweden,Slovakia and others countries but the one i want, I've looked briefly at the documentation and someone suggested region parameter in the URL however even with `region=af`it still returns different results.

Probably an easy fix but i've not found anything yet, i appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using

components=country:AF as a work around although the data is not always complete but works